# The Title of my website isn't showing in the TAB after hosting it?

Tags: html, css, web-hosting, title, favicon

I'm a newbie in web development just started learning!
after i finished my first portfolio i tried hosting it in **"www.000webhost.com"** everything is working fine but the title and the favicon aren't showing at all .
but launching the index.html in my browser it works so fine!
here is the head code :

```
<head>
  <title>E-Sabri | Welcome</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
        <link rel="icon" href="img/l.ico">
        <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Barlow+Condensed" rel="stylesheet"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/aos/dist/aos.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
        <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300" rel="stylesheet"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/simplebar@latest/dist/simplebar.css" />
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/simplebar@latest/dist/simplebar.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://a2.muscache.com/airbnb/static/libs_jquery_2x-4c61948b1a5fa686ed70f7b9bf4a18c9.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://use.typekit.net/iun0wqe.js"></script>
        <script>try{Typekit.load({ async: true });}catch(e){}</script>
        <script src="css/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet"> 
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Slabo+27px" rel="stylesheet"> 
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Saira+Extra+Condensed" rel="stylesheet"> 
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Vollkorn+SC" rel="stylesheet"> 
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

</head>
```

I'm looking forward to your answers thanks for your help ! 
The website url is : **www.Esabri.tk**

Comment: My bad i forget it i edited my post!,
the url is **www.eSabri.tk**

Comment: http://www.esabri.tk is a frameset. The actual content of the site is in http://esabri.000webhostapp.com/ and if you load that into your browser, it does show your title. I'm not sure there's a solution, other than trying to find another free hosting site.

Comment: Thank you sir! its working now ! and i see even clearer ! do you know any other free hosting sites ?

Answer (score 0):

TLD services (like TK domains) offer two ways of shorten URL,

- Redirect
- iFrame

You are using the iFrame method, change it to 'Redirect' in the URL settings.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply, i changed to Redirect and its working but when i open **www.esabri.tk** it shows **http://esabri.000webhostapp.com/** in the url is there a way to change that ?

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**
After trying over and over i decided to not park my domain but to **POINT IT** and it worked so fine ! thanks everyone for your answers have a good day